# ADFS login using UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, adfs

In Safari ADFS login is working. Unfortunately using UIWebView it does not work (the credentials dialog does not appear). How can this issue be solved? Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've found the answer, but we're actually rendering the login in Safari (which does support ADFS) and use a callback (and scheme in the pList) to return to our App... you could try that.